# $f(x)$ is differentiable on $R$ and $f(\pi) = f(0)$. Given $g(x) = \sin 2x +3f(x)$. Prove that there is $0 < c < \pi$ that $g'(c) = 0$.

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)$ is differentiable on $R$ and $f(\pi) = f(0)$. Given $g(x) = \sin 2x +3f(x)$. Prove that there is $0 < c < \pi$ that $g'(c) = 0$.

Well, it is PRETTY simple with Rolle. but I can't manage to prove that $g(0) = g(\pi) = 0$ because I don't know how do show that $f(0) = f(\pi)$.

$g(0) = \sin 0 +3f(0) = ?$

$g(\pi) = \sin 0 +3f(\pi) = ?$

What am I missing here? maybe the question is perhaps missing $f(\pi) = f(0) = 0$

Comment: The question gives you the fact that $f(\pi) = f(0)$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Haha! That's totally true. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prove that $g(0)$ and $g(\pi)$ are both zero. Showing that $g(0) = g(\pi)$ is sufficient, because then the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) guarantees that there exists a $c \in (0,\pi)$ such that $g'(c) = \dfrac{g(\pi)-g(0)}{\pi-0} = \dfrac{0}{\pi} = 0$, which is what you need to prove.

Comment: Wow, I am so stupid. I got it now. $g(0) = g(\pi)$ from the fact that $f(\pi) = f(0)$. Thanks!